# Not able to create Access.Application object

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I saw this question a lot and tried all the methods, but when I am running below code it's giving me error.

I am not able to figure it out what is wrong.

```
Dim appAccess As Object
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
```

ActiveX component can't create object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveX component can't create object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656934/activex-component-cant-create-object)

Comment: Also, you could check this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/319844/you-receive-a-activex-component-can-t-create-object-error-message-when

Comment: Is **Access** installed on the machine?